# Physical memory sharing between two native processes in Android

Tags: android, c++, memory-management, android-ndk

For efficiency, I want to allow two native processes (implemented in C++ and compiled using NDK) access to a shared memory region. Think of them as manipulating the same portion in RAM. Is there any **easy** or "official" way to achieve this.

**Note**: This question might be related to [Shared memory region in NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864778/shared-memory-region-in-ndk) without Java involvement. As a result, I cannot use Android's `Service` to pass descriptor around and using `MemoryFile` is not quite an option.