# How to use Shared Memory (IPC) in Android

Tags: android, c, linux, shared-memory

I've already written a simple Shared Memory C program in Linux. 
How can I use Shared Memory (or should I call it "ashmem?") in Android? 
I hope you can give me a step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what worked for me:
1) Open a MemoryFile object: mFile;
2) create a service to map it to ashem using mmap;
3) Return the native file descriptor (fd) to client that binds to your service using ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;
4) Create JNI for the client that takes the fd and map to ashes using mmap;
5) Create InputStream using this fd and now the client can read/write the same memory area using InputStream object.
This [link](https://vec.io/posts/andriod-ipc-shared-memory-with-ashmem-memoryfile-and-binder) shows how to map a MemoryFile to ashem. This [link](http://bina-soft.blogspot.com/2013/09/shared-memory-in-android-applications.html) shows how to send native file descriptor (fd) to client through AIDL and ParcelFileDescriptor to client.

On the server side, you will need create:
1) A service & AIDL that passes native fd to client through ParcelFileDescriptor;
2) A JNI on the service side that does the mapping.

On the client:
1) Methods to Bind to service and then call service to get native fd;
2) A JNI that maps the fd to ashem.

The mapped memory region can then be read/write by the service & client.

Answer (score 4):

A process creates a new ashmem area with the following steps:

(1) Open the device file, “/dev/ashmem” and get the file descriptor. 
(2) Call the ASHMEM_SET_NAME ioctl to set the ashmem name. It appears to be the virtual device file, so if you name it “my_mem” the file name changes to “/dev/ashmem/my_mem”.
(3) Call the ASHMEM_SET_SIZE ioctl to set the ashmem size, in bytes.

The cutils library has a function “ashmem_create_region” which wraps up these steps into a single function call:

```
int fd = ashmem_create_region("my_mem", PAGE_SIZE * 20);
```

The file descriptor can be shared with other processes. Android provides a special way to share file descriptors between cousin-processes, using another service called “binder”. Then each process mmaps the file:

```
char *map = mmap(NULL, PAGE_SIZE * 20, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                                       MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

and, voila! Instant shared memory.

Comment: I'm back again man... Using AOSP, I have made a "Hello World" C program that can be run natively in Android. I wanted to make that "Hello World" program to have an ashmem capability. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use binder IPC in Android. I think the binder uses the kernel memory, which is shared across all process, for Inter process communication.

Comment: Binder is limited to [transactions of 1 Mb or less](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException), so if you need larger, `ashmem` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to use shared memory API's here is a solution
https://github.com/pelya/android-shmem

Like a magic, it works perfectly. You can use shared memory in android across independent processes using shmget(), shmat() and shmdt() API's seamlessly. Give it a try.