# UNIX SOCKET - direct write into socket's memory possible?

Tags: c, shared-memory, unix-socket

In my software, I'm using a **PF_UNIX**-socket for IPC.

Until now I need to allocate a (pre-)buffer via `malloc` to prepare the data before writing it via `write` into the buffer.

Now I was wondering:

The socket-fd already has a buffer of eg. 64kb, so why can't I simply directly prepare & write my data into that buffer like in this way:

```
// stupid example-code, don't copy
void *fd_buffer = get_buffer_of_fd(fd)
fd_buffer[0] = 1
fd_buffer[1] = 2
fd_buffer[2] = 3
memcpy(fd_buffer, 5, 5)
...
commit_buffer_of_fd(fd, xbytes); // xBytes is DYNAMIC and not known until this point!!
```

If this would be possible, I could save the roundtrip of copying into the pre-buffer, writing into the socket from the pre-buffer and even allocate the pre-buffer.

Has anyone an idea if that is possible?

Comment: I am fairly sure what you want is not supported by anything. Also if the time it takes to copy data on a socket is such a big deal why don't you just use shared memory to communicate? It will be faster, cleaner and actually supported.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedbacks. It's no big deal, I just searched for maybe better ways :-) As I'm on Android there is sadly no method for shared memory. Thank you very much!

Comment: Some exmaples on splicing: http://ogris.de/howtos/splice.html

Comment: @MartinM. You sure? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099904/how-to-use-shared-memory-ipc-in-android http://elinux.org/Android_Kernel_Features#ashmem

Comment: Good hint, thank you I will analyze this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The socket buffer is owned by the kernel, you will never be allowed to write into kernel space. Never, ever. Too much of a security risk.

The only way to do zero-copy is to use `vmsplice(2)`, but it is not officially supported for sockets and is not recommended to use for anything other then pipes.

If you do decide to use `vmsplice`, keep in mind that you must then commit your data in chunks of pages `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`. Also it is a Linux only syscall and not portable.

Comment: Isn't a socket a pipe?  I thought sockets were pretty much the major justification for `splice` e.g. `sendfile`.

Comment: @Duck A pipe is essentially just a fifo with a certain buffer. A socket has an underlying protocol, it's associated control stack and other socket control methods aside from being generally bi-directional. It's a far more complex structure and `splice`/`vmsplice` were not designed for use with sockets.

Comment: Pipes, fifos and sockets all fall under the general term pipe.  A socket may or may not have an underlying protocol, e.g. the domain sockets of OP's question, which are in effect just a kernel managed buffer with socket semantics.  Splicing to and from tcp sockets has been (officially or not) supported for 4 or 5 years now since 2.6.25