# Interact with C++ program from android using parcelable class

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Basically, I have a C++ program that finds the sum of two numbers given. I need to provide the two numbers to the C++ program as input using my android app and then display the result in my android app. I guess I need to use parcelable class. Can someone please tell me the steps to be followed?
Edit: I forgot to mention that the C++ program that I intend to communicate with is an executable program (sum.exe)

Comment: Welcome on board. Please post some code you have already tried.

Comment: Why do you think that you need a `Parcelable` object? What's wrong with `int/long/float`?

Comment: I haven't started with coding yet as I do not have the idea how to do it. Is it possible to create such an app that communicates with C++ program in first place?

Comment: The C++ part would be a shared object (i.e. a library), not a standalone program. But yes, it's possible. Read up on the Android NDK.

Comment: Note that executable programs on Linux don't usually have **.exe** suffix. If you expect to reuse a Windows executable, you will find that these cannot run on Android.

Answer (score 0):

To run a C++ executable on Android, you can use something like `Runtime.exec("sum 1 2")`. There are a lot of tutorials, e.g. https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/. The output (**stdout** and **stderr**) can be parsed, too. A more sophisticated way is to use `ProcessBuilder`, but the idea is the same.

If you want your executable to keep running in background, and send the numbers to crunch once in a while, you can either use input pipe, or some IPC protocol. Shared memory works well, see e.g. *[How to use Shared Memory (IPC) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099904/how-to-use-shared-memory-ipc-in-android)*.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JNI code, take a look here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo025

where you can find super simple code with C++ being called via JNI wrapper from Java.