# Page curl effect for Activities in Android like as Iphone is it possible?

Tags: android, page-curl

I need page curl effect for Android Activities.

I have two pages(Activities),how can I go for next page(activity) by using page curl in android.

Click this link for reference [Android Page Curl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVZHN_o45sg) . and 
                               [Page Curl Effect on Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg04wfnDpiQ)

any answers and helps are great appreciation.

Comment: there is no complete information right?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - do not do things like this with Activities:)
But if you are really want to do it here is the way you looking for.

1. Disable transition animations for this two Activities.
2. Save a screenshot of your current activity(by using [getDrawingCache()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache())) and send it to second activity(or draw a view using WindowManager, there is a very simple [lib](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut) for it). Most efficient way i know is using [MemoryFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MemoryFile.html), details could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165216/what-is-the-use-of-memoryfile-in-android). Or just use a static reference to a bitmap object(be careful with it).
3. Launch second activity without animation and then start animating your bitmap over existing activity content by using [one of this libs](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=curl)
4. It could be tricky to pass touch events from one Activity to another or window manager. Honestly, I don't know how you could effectively do it. One of the variants is sending [fake touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396059/how-to-simulate-a-touch-event-in-android).

That's all I think. In single Activity, it would be much easily and you could still wrap all your logic into View or Fragment.