# How to get audio file metadata from custom content provider?

Tags: android, metadata, android-contentprovider

I have an app that serves as a *content provider* that stores ***.mp3*** files.

F.e. `content://.../player/audio.mp3`

**How can i get the metadata of these files?**

---

When I stored the data in `file:///.../player/audio.mp3` I used `MediaMetadataRetriever()` so the code looked like this:

```
    fun metadataDuration(uri: Uri): Long {
        val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
        retriever.setDataSource(context, uri)
        return retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION)!!.toLong()
    }
```

But if I try to use `uri` as `content://.../player/audio.mp3` I get errors:

```
W/System.err:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
W/System.err:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:151)
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:705)
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1687)
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1503)
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1420)
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:171)
```

Comment: "if I try to paste uri as content://.../player/audio.mp3 I get errors" -- if by "paste" you mean that you hard-coded that value, you will not hae permission to that content, most likely.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I have access to all content. I can read and write files using my content provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I couldn't use `MediaDataRetriever / FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever` with `Content Provider` URIs:

```
fun metadataDuration(uri: Uri): Long {
        val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
        retriever.setDataSource(context, uri)
        return retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION)!!.toLong()
    }
```

so this code didn't work, as I said in the question.

---

The only thing I can do with each file from the `Content Provider` is to read the `ByteArray` of the file.

**Solution:**

I found a way to create file and get the `File Descriptor` , so I can use `MediaDataRetriever / FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever`

I used:
[MemoryFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MemoryFile)

```
val newMemoryFile = MemoryFile(memoryFileName, fileContent.size)
newMemoryFile.writeBytes(fileContent, 0, 0, fileContent.size)
val fd = getFileDescriptor(newMemoryFile)
val mmr = FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever()
mmr.setDataSource(fd)
val duration = mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION).toLong()
mmr.release()
newMemoryFile.close()
```

---

To get File Descriptor I used this code: [MemoryFileGetFileDescriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20462008/14855622)